# Find the volume of the following solid

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, volume, multiple-integral

Find the volume of the solid in $\mathbb{R}^3 $ under paraboloid $\{x_1^2+x_2^2-x_3=0\}$ and above the square $[0,1]^2$.

I want to calculate $\int_{\{x_1^2+x_2^2-x_3 \le 0 \ and \ 0 \le x_1,x_2 \le 1\}}1 dx_1dx_2dx_3$ , but I'm not sure how to split it to 3 integrals...any help?

Comment: $$\iint_{(0,1)^2}\left(x_1^2+x_2^2\right)\,dx_1\,dx_2 = \frac{2}{3}.$$

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio I know that the final answer is $2/3$ , I already had it.What I don't know is,what should be the boundaries for $x_3$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calculate: 
$$
\text{Volume}=\int_0^1 \int_0^1 \int_0^{x_1^2+x_2^2} dx_3 dx_1 dx_2. 
$$

Comment: Why the upper boundary of $x_3$ is $x_1^2+x_2^2$?

Comment: @ChikChak This is because the solid is bounded above by the surface $x_3=x_1^2+x_2^2$ and bounded below by the plane $x_3=0$. It might help if you convert your variables $x_1$, $x_2$, $x_3$ to $x$, $y$, $z$ and repeat the visualization.